# VS Express Icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, icons

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 to create desktop applications (c# WPF and forms) on Windows 7 Pro.  I have read that Paint will create icon files (as I understand they are some kind of bitmap but with an ico extension).  When I start with an existing and usable icon, change it in paint and save it I can no longer use it for the icon in my applications.  Has anyone actually been able to do this?  I've read several posts with conflicting information but it seems that it may be possible.  I think that the normal paid version of VS will make this easier, but I'm an architect (buildings) not a software developer so not likely to spend money to get that functionality.

Comment: What are you saving as?

Comment: I'm saving as a 24 bit bmp.

Comment: You need to save your icon as `.ico` extension, otherwise Visual Studio will not see it.

Comment: Yes, I save as, pick the 24 bit bmp type, and name the file something like myicon.ico.  VS sees it, but when I try to use select it as the project icon in the project properties it gives an error (incorrect format or something similar).  I am starting with an existing (and usable) ico file that I read into paint, modify and save out as I describe.

Comment: Try creating your icon [here](http://www.xiconeditor.com) and use it Visual Studio. It looks like you're doing something in the `Paint`.

Answer (score 0):

If you include your icon file as a file in your project (Add Existing Item...), you can then right click on it, and select Open.

This will open an icon editor inside VS.  An toolbar will appear that will have all the tools that you want to help edit your file.

You can do the same thing with just about any type of image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if you re read my question I am using VS Express, which does not have the functionality that you describe.  I realize that the for pay versions have this capability.

Comment: I believe VS Express does have this icon editor just that you are limited to 16 colours as in the screen shot above. I believe the full version has the full RGB range. If you double click on your icon within VS it will most likely open in MS Paint if it has colours outside of this 16 colour range. If you go File->New->Icon you will get a 16x16 and a 32x32 default icon by default which you can edit directly or within MS Paint copy then paste over your icon in the VS Express icon editor. If the colour scale changes after pasting to 16 colour then you know that VS Express cannot handle it.